# Make invisible field based on current user groups (self.env.user.has_group not working) Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need to make some  fields invisible to administrator. So, I create a function field to hold a boolean value.
The function is below:

```
check_user = fields.Boolean(string='user', compute='_compute_user_check', default=False)

    def _compute_user_check(self):
        if self.env.user.has_group('base.user_admin'):
            self.check_user = True
```

and on XML I use:

```
<field name="model">res.users</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <group string="Test" attrs="{'invisible': [('check_user','=', True)]}" >
                    </group>
                    <field name="check_user" invisible="1"/>
                </group>
            </field>
```

Apparently check_user always have True value.
What's wrong in my code ? Any help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to always set value a value.
Try that.

```py
def _compute_user_check(self):
    if self.env.user.has_group('base.user_admin'):
        self.check_user = True
    else:
        self.check_user = False
```

Comment: Paxmees, I got the same result : check_user always have True value.

Answer (score 0):

Ing

It is not working due to the field which you try to add in `domain` followed by the `search` and the field is not `store` in the database.

```
check_user = fields.Boolean(string='user', compute='_compute_user_check', default=False, store=True)
```

Also, you can add depends which is invoke the method.

```
@api.depends('field1', 'field2')
def _compute_user_check(self):
    if self.env.user.has_group('base.user_admin'):
        self.check_user = True
```